# ElasticSearch на VPS

Tags: vps, elasticsearch, xen

Есть `VPS` с 1 ядром и 1Гб памяти на `Xen`. Нам нем работает `Apache Tomcat` и `PostgreSQL`. Остается где-то примерно 0.5Гб памяти свободно. Насколько разумно поставить туда `ElasticSearch` для полнотекстового поиска?

Хватит ли ресурсов сервера или для таких вещей нужен выделенный сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать `ElasticSearch` только для полнотекстового поиска, то целесообразней использовать [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Он лёгкий и покроет все ваши нужды на начальном этапе. ES - это достаточно тяжелый продукт, но и возможностей у него гораздо больше.